# Объясните подробно, каждую строчку кода, как описать bitmap?

Tags: delphi, графика

Как в dеlphi описать объект bitmap, связать его с контекстом окна, и рисовать битмапе? Приведите пжл в пример **минимальный** код.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помещаем на форму компонент TImage (с именем image). Далее в любой удобный момент делаем:

```
// Создаем битмар
b := TBitMap.create;

// Задаем размеры BitMap, равные размерам image
b.Height:=image.Height;
b.Width:=image.Width;

// TODO: Рисуем на битмапе или загружаем картинку из файла
// ...

// Показываем содержимое на экране
image.Picture.Assign(b);

// Очищаем память
b.Free;
```

Comment: Вы просто не так поняли вопрос =)

Answer (score 1):

Пример, как рисовать на рабочем столе:

```
var bmp:Tbitmap; 
begin
bmp:=Tbitmap.Create;
bmp.canvas.Handle:=getdc(0);       //получаем контекст(HDC) рабочего стола 
bmp.canvas.Rectangle(0,0,200,100); // А далее рисуем, как в обычном TbitMap`е =)
```